# How does SSIS determine execution order on the control flow?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, control-flow

### Summary:

I would like to find a way to tell SSIS, when running multiple executables in parallel, which ones should be run first.  There is plenty of material on the Internet about the MaxConcurrentExecutables property, but no information about how SSIS decides what order to run the executables in.

I'm looking for an answer that describes the mechanism that SSIS uses to determine the runtime order of executables when no precedence constraints exist, and the number of executables is greater than the maximum concurrent executables.

### More Details:

I have a master SSIS package that is calling a large number of Staging packages, each of which is responsible for copying data into a different table on our Staging database. The time these child packages take to execute varies widely, from < 1 minute to > 20 minutes.

To use my time best, I would like the longer-running packages to run first, then the medium packages, then the small ones.

Ideally, I would be able to sort the packages into priority containers (A,B,C), then have the SSIS engine work on the containers in order.  I **don't** want to wait for A to complete before starting B: rather, I'd like all the executables in A to be started before SSIS begins working on B.

[image]

Is there any way to have SSIS start all of the tasks in Container A before it starts working on Container B? Failing that, can anyone describe the logic that SSIS uses to determine the run order?

Answer (score 0):

> The MaxConcurrentExecutables determines the number of control flow items that can be executed in parallel and defaulted to -1. This is equivalent to the number of processors plus 2.

In your case the execution of SEQC A, SEQC B and SEQC C starts at the same time and continues with each Execute Package Task in each group until it finishes them all.
So to best utilise the processing capacity and to shorten the execution time, you need to split the packages into each group such a way each group takes roughly the same time to finish all EP tasks.

> For example if you have Package1(30mins), Package2(10mins), Package3(8mins), Package4(8mins), splitting this the following way gives optimum performance.

```html
<table border=1 cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="5px">
  <tr>
  <th>SEQC A</th><th>SEQC B</th></tr>
<tr><td>Package1</td><td>Package2</td>  </tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Package3</td>  </tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Package4</td>  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Unfortunately, simply splitting the packages into separate containers doesn't change the runtime behavior.  I've seen cases where, to borrow from your example above, Package4 and Package2 will start and run first, and Package1 will not be started until one of them has finished. I'm looking for a way to tell SSIS that I want to give the executables in `SEQC A` a higher priority than those in `SEQC B`, so it will focus on them first.

Comment: @AHiggins Unless I'm missing something In my example if we leave the MaxConcurrentExecutables to default value -1, The Master package starts executing SEQC A and SEQC B at the same time. i.e. Package 1 and Package 2 start in parallel, while Package 1 is being executed (takes 30mins) Package 2, 3 and 4 will be finished in the same order.  I have just now tested this with a quick example, also we have similar setup with 4 groups and all start at same time and I have an audit table which confirms this with the start time of each package.

Comment: Oh - are you connecting the items in `SEQC B` with precedence constraints?

Comment: Yes, I'm using precedence constraints. Sorry! I just saw that you are not using precedence constraints, that is why the random behaviour. SSIS may allocate all available threads to one group. To avoid this can you not use a script component to pass the package name to be executed to the EP task. That way you can control the order of execution.

Comment: OK that explains the confusion!  I'm deliberately trying to avoid the use of constraints, as that limits SSIS to the pre-selected path.  If Package1 happens to finish before Package3, then I want the 'thread' that was previously running Package1 to go ahead and start working on Package4, rather than wait for Package3 to finish.

Comment: Just few thoughts: Since there are no precedence constraints the tasks are randomly selected I guess (even having them in different groups doesn’t make a difference), but that should not be a problem as all the available threads will continue to run until the last task is finished. When I tested this with some 30 sample tasks none of the threads was idle until all the tasks were finished. I don’t know why in your case some threads were waiting?

Comment: Thread management isn't the problem: as you said, when no precedence constraints are used there are no idle threads until all tasks are finished. The problem described in my question is a matter of prioritizing which tasks run first, so that a long-running task gets started early in the process.